# How to create a batch(multipart/mixed) with boundary in c# using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, post, webrequest

I'm trying to create a batch(multipart/mixed) with boundary in c# using `HttpWebRequest` but always it returns an error :

> "The batch request must have a boundary specification in the
>   \"Content-Type\" header."

if I remove the boundary the error is the same but about boundary. Could anyone create a little example of it?

My data is

```
--batch
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=changeset
--changeset
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary 
Content-ID: 1
--changeset
PUT     
https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/Products(20199461)/Images('ImageFree1')?
access_token=-qK4l1JoGct6BMFXGY6t24VHbaCNpXMFsqns6QioOwE-15035
Content-type: application/json\r\n{\"Url\":\"http://iguanasell-
pics.com/photos/021G/cat/Montegrappa-Ducale-Ballpoint-pen-Mother-of-
Pearl-Resin-Rose-gold-trim-1.jpg\"}
--changeset-- 
--batch--
```

And my code:

```
String token= "abcd1234";
var requestMulti = 
HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/$batch?
access_token=" + token);
requestMulti.ContentType = "multipart/mixed;boundary=changeset";
requestMulti.Method = "POST";`
```

Thanks!

Comment: First put double quotes around "abcd1234". I think you have a casting issue. Try : HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/$batch?
access_token=" + token) as HttpWebRequest;

Comment: Uops sorry, I have "" just i wrote here simplified and I forgot to add it!

Comment: Did you try the cast?